# 見出しタグから目次を作りたい

Tags: html

見出しタグ`<h2>,<h3>`などから目次を生成し、ページ内にリンクを張りたいと考えています。
JS等で自動で生成するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jSで実装した場合には下記のような形になります。

```
$(function(){// H2~H4タグから目次を自動生成
    var idcount = 1;
    var toc = '';
    var currentlevel = 0;
    $("h2,h3,h4:header", $("#article")).each(function(){
        this.id = "chapter-" + idcount;
        idcount++;
        var tag = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        var level = 0;
        if( tag == "h2") {
            level = 1;
        }else if( tag == "h3") {
            level = 2;
        } else if( tag == "h4") {
            level = 3;
        }
        while(currentlevel < level) {
            toc += '<ol class="chapter">';
            currentlevel++;
        }
        while(currentlevel > level) {
            toc += "<\/ol>";
            currentlevel--;
        }
        toc += '<li><a href="#' + this.id + '">' + $(this).html() + "<\/a><\/li>\n";

    });
    while(currentlevel > 0) {
        toc += "<\/ol>";
        currentlevel--;
    }
    $("#index").html(toc);
});
```